# No mapping for GET /swagger-ui.html

Tags: java, spring-boot, springfox

I am new in programming world.
I tried use http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html but logs return
2022-11-03 04:27:28.476  WARN 13844 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /swagger-ui.html

{

```
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'
```

}

(sorry, for my english language)

```
package com.crud.tasks.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class CoreConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

```
package com.crud.tasks;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
public class TasksApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(TasksApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to visualize API's using `Swagger`, I'd suggest to follow this simple tutorial.

No additional configurations required !

**Simple steps**

1. Add below dependency

```
<groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>

<artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>

<version>1.6.4</version>
```

2. Access API after starting your Spring boot app at following path in browser

`http://localhost:your_port/v3/api-docs/`

3. Use a custom path by modifying property , for e.g.

`springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs`

4. Default integration is also available with below link

`http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`

**Follow this short and sweet tutorial** https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation

Comment: I am working in spring-boot v3.1.4 and I've tried so many ways to implement swagger using io.springfox. Same result as in this question. Thankfully, this one using openapi works perfectly. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems implementing Swagger using 'spring fox swagger ui' , So Instead of it you can use 'Springdoc-open-api'.
You may follow [Swagger with openAPI](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot_swagger3) .